# How to access your Samba Server from an iPad?

Tags: samba, ios

How do I access your Samba Server from an iPad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use one of two [Documents by Readdle](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8) (Free) or [File Explorer](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/fileexplorer-file-manager/id510282524?mt=8) (Free) then I go to add, and WINDOWS - on File Explorer scroll down and you'll see your server and on documents put in your Hostname - default is UBUNTU.

Hope this help fo anyone like me!